# How to automatically install plugins in new dev environment

Tags: cordova-cli, cordova-5.0.0

I have a Cordova 5.1.1 project initiated in a windows pc. I uploaded to the source control only this folders and files:
 - www folder
 - the fetch.json and android.json files of plugins folder
 - the platforms.json file of the platform folder
 - the hooks folder
 - the build.json and config.xml files of the root

When I download the project in a mac PC to build for iOS, I added the ios platform, but when I list pluygins ionly whitelist apprears. How can I do to cordova to install automatically plugins from fetch.json file?